# How to fill input fields correctly with a preset (and update them) using AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, input, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-model, two-way-binding

Please, check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/12035/). When you add a dim preset, it is added correctly to `$scope.packData`, but it won't fill correctly the input fields. After that if you try to update the `$scope.packData` directly from the input field, it won't work. It does only from the dim preset.
What am I missing here?

Below is the code.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

//myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {});
//myApp.factory('myService', function() {});

function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.packData = [{
    length: null,
    width: null,
    height: null
  }];

  $scope.addNewpack = function() {
    $scope.packData.push({
      length: null,
      width: null,
      height: null
    });
  };

  $scope.removepack = function(index) {
    if ($scope.packData.length != 1) {
      $scope.packData.splice(index, 1);
    }
  };

  $scope.dimPresets = [{
    length: 73,
    width: 54,
    height: 45,
    tare: 2
  }, {
    length: 11,
    width: 11,
    height: 11,
    tare: 1
  }, {
    length: 23,
    width: 23,
    height: 23,
    tare: 4
  }, {
    length: 41,
    width: 52,
    height: 63,
    tare: 6
  }];

  $scope.fillLastpack = function(length, width, height, tare) {
    var lastpack = $scope.packData.length - 1;
    $scope.packData[lastpack] = [{
      "length": length,
      "width": width,
      "height": height
    }];
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl" ng-app="myApp">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-inline">
        <div class="form-group-sm">
          <fieldset data-ng-repeat="pack in packData" style="padding-bottom:5px;">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-4">Pack {{$index+1}}: </label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" style="width:80px;" id="length" ng-model="pack.length" name="" placeholder="length">
            <input type="number" class="form-control" style="width:80px;" id="width" ng-model="pack.width" name="" placeholder="width">
            <input type="number" class="form-control" style="width:80px;" id="height" ng-model="pack.height" name="" placeholder="height">
            <button ng-click="removepack($index)" ng-hide="packData.length==1">-</button>
          </fieldset>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group-sm" style="padding-top:5px;">
        <span class="col-sm-4"></span>
        <button ng-click="addNewpack()">Add pack</button>
      </div>
      <div>{{packData}}</div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group-sm">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div class="btn-group-sm" uib-dropdown>
            <span>Add dim: </span>
            <ul>
              <li ng-repeat="preset in dimPresets" ng-click="fillLastpack(preset.length, preset.width, preset.height, preset.tare)">
                <a href="">{{preset.length}}cm x {{preset.width}}cm x {{preset.height}}cm</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the corrected code. In your function `fillLastpack()` you were pushing an array of object into the `packData` array instead you just have to push an object.

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/12038/)**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

//myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {});
//myApp.factory('myService', function() {});

function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.packData = [{
    length: null,
    width: null,
    height: null
  }];

  $scope.addNewpack = function() {
    $scope.packData.push({
      length: null,
      width: null,
      height: null
    });
  };

  $scope.removepack = function(index) {
    if ($scope.packData.length != 1) {
      $scope.packData.splice(index, 1);
    }
  };

  $scope.dimPresets = [{
    length: 73,
    width: 54,
    height: 45,
    tare: 2
  }, {
    length: 11,
    width: 11,
    height: 11,
    tare: 1
  }, {
    length: 23,
    width: 23,
    height: 23,
    tare: 4
  }, {
    length: 41,
    width: 52,
    height: 63,
    tare: 6
  }];

  $scope.fillLastpack = function(length, width, height, tare) {
    var lastpack = $scope.packData.length - 1;
    $scope.packData[lastpack] = {
      "length": length,
      "width": width,
      "height": height
    };
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl" ng-app="myApp">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-inline">
        <div class="form-group-sm">
          <fieldset data-ng-repeat="pack in packData" style="padding-bottom:5px;">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-4">Pack {{$index+1}}: </label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" style="width:80px;" id="length" ng-model="pack.length" name="" placeholder="length">
            <input type="number" class="form-control" style="width:80px;" id="width" ng-model="pack.width" name="" placeholder="width">
            <input type="number" class="form-control" style="width:80px;" id="height" ng-model="pack.height" name="" placeholder="height">
            <button ng-click="removepack($index)" ng-hide="packData.length==1">-</button>
          </fieldset>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group-sm" style="padding-top:5px;">
        <span class="col-sm-4"></span>
        <button ng-click="addNewpack()">Add pack</button>
      </div>
      <div>{{packData}}</div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group-sm">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div class="btn-group-sm" uib-dropdown>
            <span>Add dim: </span>
            <ul>
              <li ng-repeat="preset in dimPresets" ng-click="fillLastpack(preset.length, preset.width, preset.height, preset.tare)">
                <a href="">{{preset.length}}cm x {{preset.width}}cm x {{preset.height}}cm</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps :)